# Shared pointers causing weird behaviour

Tags: c++, sfml

I have the following code in SFML 2.1

Class ResourceManager:

```
shared_ptr<Sprite> ResourceManager::getSprite(string name) {
    shared_ptr<Texture> texture(new Texture);
    if(!texture->loadFromFile(resPath+spritesPath+name)) 
        throw new NotSuchFileException();
    shared_ptr<Sprite> sprite(new Sprite(*texture));
    return sprite;
}
```

Main method: (I'll omit most of the irrelevant code

```
shared_ptr<Sprite> sprite = ResourceManager::getSprite("sprite.png");

...

while(renderWindow.isOpen()) 
    renderWindow.draw(*sprite);
```

Oddly enough this makes my sprite render completely white, but if I do this instead:

```
shared_ptr<Sprite> ResourceManager::getSprite(string name) {
    Texture* texture = new Texture; // <------- From shared pointer to pointer
    if(!texture->loadFromFile(resPath+spritesPath+name)) 
        throw new NotSuchFileException();
    shared_ptr<Sprite> sprite(new Sprite(*texture));
    return sprite;
}
```

It works perfectly.

So what's happening here? I assumed the shared pointer would work just as a pointer. Could it be that it's getting deleted? My main method is keeping a reference to it so I don't really understand what's going on here :S

EDIT: I'm perfectly aware deleting the sprite won't delete the texture and this is generating a memory leak I'd have to handle, that's why I'm trying to use smart pointers on the first place...

Comment: You should use `make_shared` instead of explicitly constructing `shared_ptr`s - it's more concise.

Comment: Do not do `throw new Exception`, that's a memory leak.

Comment: Note that the "works perfectly" version leaks the `new Texture`, (unless you add a custom deleter to your `shared_ptr` that then deletes the Texture)

Answer (score 5):

I may be way off here but I thought it was worth a try:

If the sprite class constructor takes a regular Texture * or a Texture reference (as opposed to it taking and storing a shared pointer) then when the shared_ptr goes out of scope in getSprite the texture will be destroyed (because no shared_ptr's to the texture exist after that point).

Comment: The constructor call (from the API documentation) is:

    sf::Sprite::Sprite(const Texture & texture) so it's doing a pass by reference. That would technically work the same as a pointer right?

Comment: Yeah. So when you leave getSprite, no shared_ptr<Texture> exists - so in the shared_ptr destructor it destroys the resource. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

Comment: So the only way would be to keep the texture around somewhere. That gave me the idea of making a texture cache for the resource manager, may I ask if using shared_ptr would break an STL container like map?

Answer (score 1):

Your shared pointer in the first is falling out of scope and deleting the reference to the loaded texture. You need to save a reference to your sf::Texture instance in order to retain the instance, so you want something like this (untested code):

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> mLoadedTextures;

std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> ResourceManager::getSprite(std::string name) {
    auto found = mLoadedTextures.find(name);
    if (found == mLoadedTextures.end()) {
        std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> texture(new sf::Texture());
        if (!texture->loadFromFile(resPath+spritesPath+name)) {
            // ERROR: Unable to find/load texture
        }
        auto inserted = mLoadedTextures.insert(std::make_pair(name, std::move(texture)));
        if (!inserted.second)) {
            // ERROR: Unable to insert into map
        }
        found = inserted.first;
    }
    shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> sprite(new sf::Sprite(*found.second));
    return sprite;
}
```

You should reconsider how your ResourceManager is operating, however. You ideally would do all your loading up front and place all those textures in a map owned by your resource manager. Then creating a sprite won't ever have to take the performance hit of loading a texture "on the critical path".

If you read "SFML Game Development" they cover this topic pretty well.

http://www.packtpub.com/sfml-game-development/book

Answer (score 0):

Objects of `sf::Sprite` are pretty lightweight (it's really just a container for a quad and some more information), so I wouldn't even bother having them managed in some kind of ressource manager.

The far heavier object is the texture, so only manage that one.

As mentioned already, the texture's smart pointer is going out of scope and therefore the texture is deleted.

Even if each and every entity in your game has its own sprite it won't impact performance that bad (compared to reusing one sprite).

So to fix your issue, manage the texture based on their path, rather than the sprites.